# How to use a global selector to respond to all click events except on one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, global

If I have a button:

```
<button id="button1">
```

Normally I would write:

```
$("#button1").click(function ()
{    
    //do something
}
```

But I want to define a function that responds to all click events **except** when someone clicks on this button.

Is there a selector that would allow me to target all other clickable elements in the document except `button1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you have accepted the answer above but I would advise strongly against this.
You can use event delegation to do what you want with a lot less overhead to the dom.

I know .live() exists but too many live handlers also impact performance. I prefer event delegation old style.

Demo [here](http://jsbin.com/umaga)

```
$(function(){
    $('body').click( clickFn );
  });

  function clickFn( ev ) {

    if (ev.target.id != 'button1' ){
       //do your stuff
       console.log('not a #button1 click');
    }

  }
```

Comment: Event delegation is baked right into jQuery with live() -> http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

Comment: yeah but it has its own overheads.

Comment: Thanks. I have started trying to implement your solution in my code but I'm confused about the syntax you used. I have added a new question to try to clarify my confusion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147864/correct-syntax-for-defining-an-event-delegator

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [:not selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not):

```
$('button:not(#button1)').click(function(){
  //Do something
});
```

The above selector will match all the button elements, except the one with id = "button1".

If you want really to select all the elements under the body tag, you can use the ["All"](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/all) (`*`) selector, and also exclude the elements with [:not(selector)](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not) or [.not(expr)](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/not#expr):

```
$('body *:not(#button1)').click(function(){
  //Do something
});
```

Or

```
$('body *').not('#button1').click(function(){
  //Do something
});
```

If you do so, you could have some event bubbling or propagation issues, you can handle this with the [event.stopPropagation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29) function.

Comment: Not a good solution. You could end up attaching 100's of click events. Event Delegation would be best here where you check the event.target

Comment: @redsquare - In the case of the body selector maybe. But in the case of 'button:not(#button1)', you only add as many click events as you have buttons. I think I understand your concern though.

Answer (score 1):

The current CSS 3 Selectors Candidate Recommendation defines the [`:root` pseuedo class](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#root-pseudo).

> The `:root` pseudo-class represents an element that is the root of the document. In HTML 4, this is always the `HTML` element.

You could attach an event listener to the root and then check which element received the click. If it's the element you want to ignore return, otherwise do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: Sounds browser dependent if it's a candidate spec.

Comment: The selector engines provided by JavaScript libraries like jQuery implement CSS 3 Selectors, e.g. you can use selectors in jQuery that aren't implemented by the browser quite happily.