# Correct syntax for defining an event delegator

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

Normally you write a handler for a button click like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $("button").click(function()
  {    
    doSomething();
  });
});
```

But in the case of an [event delegator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146823/how-to-use-a-global-selector-to-respond-to-all-click-events-except-on-one-element/1146963#1146963), to respond to an event with a function such as this:

```
  function doSomething(event)
  {
    if (ev.target.id == 'button1' )
    {
       //do your stuff
       console.log('#button1 click');
    }
    else
    {
       console.log('not a #button1 click');
    }
  }
```

**What I'm confused about is the correct syntax for defining the event that calls this delegator function - this? (A):**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(function()
  {
    $('button').click(doSomething);
  });
});
```

**or this? (B):**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("button").click(doSomething);
});
```

**Which is correct and why?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In choice A you are just repeating the document.ready syntax twice.

```
// These two lines are equal
$(document).ready(fn);
$(fn);
```

All you need to do is choice B

Answer (score 1):

While choice B would certainly be the way to do this if you needed to use a separate function, i.e., in the case where you needed to invoke the function from somewhere other than a button click, my preference is usually to put the code in line.  The only other times I don't do this is when it would improve readability.

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click( function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'button1') {
           alert('button1 clicked');
        }
        ...
    });
});
```